# IE6 duplication P tag content?

Tags: html, css, debugging, internet-explorer-6

Im testing a website of mine in IE6 and for some strange reason ie6 duplicates the content within one of my tags and pastes it at the bottom of the window as seen in the image.

I've tried adding overflow:hidden, defining height and widths to the P tag with no luck, has anybody seen a bug like this before?

[image: Duplication of content]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the "IE6 Duplicate Characters Bug".

**See:** http://www.positioniseverything.net/explorer/dup-characters.html

Simple `<!-- comments -->` are making IE6 insane.

Comment: Ahh brilliant, thanks! Apparently the developers at my place have never heard of the dup content bug 8-)

Comment: If you *still* have to support IE6, I recommend you read through the entire list here: http://www.positioniseverything.net/explorer.html. A lot of IE6 bugs are known and documented, and being familiar with them really helps when you're bashing your head against the desk.

Answer (score 2):

There's a duplicate characters bug in IE6 that seems to fit what you're describing.
Check these two places:
http://www.impressivewebs.com/ie6-ghost-text-bug-with-multiple-solutions/
and
http://www.virtuosimedia.com/dev/css/ultimate-ie6-cheatsheet-how-to-fix-25-internet-explorer-6-bugs#duplicate-characters-bug
(On the second one, look for the heading 'Duplicate Characters Bug')

```
<!-- comments seem to break IE6! -->
```